# How would I train like Bobby Fischer did?

Tags: books, training, fischer

As the title suggests, I want to know how to train like Bobby Fischer did, along with what books he read during his chess training. Remember, keyword is **TRAIN**. I don’t want to be **like** him, as that is impossible, but I merely want to know how to **train** like him.

Comment: Step 1 is developing an uncontrollable obsession with chess.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be better suited for [Worldbuilding Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but as Bobby's training system you are asking for started at the precise second Bobby met the game at a young age, you will need to:

1. Return with a time machine to five years old and develop Asperger
   disorder.
2. Buy not only one but a dozen of chess boards.
3. Develop an uncontrollable obsession with chess as said, forgetting
   everything is not chess. Your mother can do those tasks and the
   school is totally unnecessary for you. You know modals and how the law 
   rules, not to enter in troubles not related with chess.
4. Play millions of games with yourself. Play chess every minute you
   don't have to eat, sleep or waste your time with adults. Use those
   books only to follow master moves and remaster the games on your
   dozen of chess board that have colonized your home (you will need to
   convince your mother for that).
5. Go to the tournaments and destroy all those poor players that read
   the text of those chess books you will take a look later to see if
   they are correct or not.
6. Continue enjoying and learning at FIDE circuit your hole life.

Comment: @Rewan Demontay The question invites to joke a bit but if I read correctly Bobby's history that's what he did. He played simultaneous at home with himself and followed masters games. For poster I have asperger disorder myself and obsession is important. Also you need to start at a young age to understand Bobby's chess knowledge. Because of neurology a kid learns much more quickly how a game rules than an adult.